# How to toggle exclusive visibility with Bootstrap classes?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

So basically I have a jQuery function attached to some folder icons that toggle the visibility of different divs:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#techfolder").click(function(){
    $("#txt").toggleClass("d-none");
  });
  $("#persfolder").click(function(){
    $("#txt2").toggleClass("d-none");
  });
  $("#linkfolder").click(function(){
    $("#txt3").toggleClass("d-none");
  });
});
```

The only problem is that if one element is visible and you don't click its folder to make it disappear before clicking another folder associated with a different element, the newly visible element appears below the first one. I want to make it so that visibility is exclusive for these elements, and only one can be showing at a time. I can't seem to figure out how to make that happen.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What will happen if user clicks on only folder that was visible? All elements will be hidden?

Comment: You'll have to keep track of the one that was clicked before and hide it when another is clicked. OR simply use siblings selector `$("#txt").siblings().removeClass('d-none');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this might not be the simplest way but what you could do is mention all unique elements within an array, then fire a check to see if the element inside the element you've clicked on is a child, then toggle the display none.

If it isn't a direct child, then fire a check to see if 'd-none' is active or not, then toggle it.

There's probably a far simpler way but this answer is based on the assumption you're keeping the HTML as you are.

```js
var arrayOfElements = [$("#txt"), $("#txt2"), $("#txt3")];

$('#techfolder, #persfolder, #linkfolder').click(function(){
 checkDisplayNone($(this));
});


function checkDisplayNone(elem) {
  innerElem =  elem.children();
  for (i = 0; i < arrayOfElements.length; i++) {
    if (innerElem[0].id !== arrayOfElements[i][0].id) {
      if (!arrayOfElements[i].hasClass('d-none'))
      arrayOfElements[i].toggleClass('d-none'); 
    } else {
     arrayOfElements[i].toggleClass('d-none');
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#techfolder {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  margin: 1rem;
}

#persfolder {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  margin: 1rem;
}

#linkfolder {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
  margin: 1rem;
}

.d-none {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<html>
<div id="techfolder">
  <div id="txt" class="d-none">
  text
  </div>
</div>
<div id="persfolder">
  <div id="txt2">
  text
  </div>
</div>
<div id="linkfolder">
  <div id="txt3">
  text
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</html>
```